# Find duplicate index in MySQL using query

Tags: mysql, indexing

I know about MySQL utility called [mysqlindexcheck](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-utilities/1.5/en/mysqlindexcheck.html). But Can I find duplicate indexes through SQL query. I tried this, but looking for any better idea or improvement

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    TABLE_NAME,
    COLUMN_NAME,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT INDEX_NAME)
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.STATISTICS
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'db_name' 
AND INDEX_NAME NOT IN ('PRIMARY')
GROUP BY COLUMN_NAME
HAVING count(DISTINCT INDEX_NAME)>1
ORDER BY TABLE_NAME ;
```

Comment: Here is a tutorial for it: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-find-duplicate-values/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the below query:

```
SELECT s.INDEXED_COL,GROUP_CONCAT(INDEX_NAME) FROM (
SELECT INDEX_NAME,GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(TABLE_NAME,'.',COLUMN_NAME) ORDER BY CONCAT(SEQ_IN_INDEX,COLUMN_NAME)) 'INDEXED_COL' FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.STATISTICS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'db?' 
GROUP BY INDEX_NAME
)as s GROUP BY INDEXED_COL HAVING COUNT(1)>1
```

**Note:** This will differentiate two composite keys in respective of column order

e.g: IND1(col1,col2) and IND2(col2,col1) will be treated as different (not duplicate) index

U may Try this (but this will not work for composite index):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
        TABLE_NAME,
        COLUMN_NAME,COUNT(1),
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT INDEX_NAME)
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.STATISTICS
    WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'db?' 
    AND INDEX_NAME NOT IN ('PRIMARY')
    AND INDEX_NAME NOT IN (SELECT CONSTRAINT_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.`REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS`)
    GROUP BY TABLE_NAME,COLUMN_NAME
    HAVING count(1)>1
    ORDER BY TABLE_NAME ;
```

Comment: surely `REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS` should be information_schema.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS

Answer (score 4):

The following query will identify candidate duplicate/redundant indexes.  If you're looking for only duplicate indices you can simply change the WHERE clause `first_part.indexed_columns LIKE CONCAT(second_part.indexed_columns, '%')` to `first_part.indexed_columns = second_part.indexed_columns`.

The query works by concatenating the columns (with `SUB_PART`) in the correct order and then checking if there is another column with the same beginning.  Please note that while this works in most cases, it does not work in all cases.  For example, different index types would show up as redundant and two indexes like `(colA)` and `(colA(10), colB)` would show up as redundant even though it's not truly a redundant index.  So I recommend using the query as a tool to find the indices and then manually verifying that they're redundant.

```
SELECT
  first_part.TABLE_NAME, 
  first_part.INDEX_NAME, 
  second_part.INDEX_NAME
FROM (
  SELECT 
    TABLE_NAME, 
    INDEX_NAME,
    GROUP_CONCAT(
      IF(SUB_PART IS NULL, 
        COLUMN_NAME, 
        CONCAT(
          COLUMN_NAME, 
          '(', 
          SUB_PART, 
          ')'
        )
      )
      ORDER BY SEQ_IN_INDEX 
      SEPARATOR ', '
    ) AS indexed_columns
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.STATISTICS
  GROUP BY TABLE_NAME, INDEX_NAME
) AS first_part
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT 
    TABLE_NAME, 
    INDEX_NAME,
    GROUP_CONCAT(
      IF(SUB_PART IS NULL, 
        COLUMN_NAME, 
        CONCAT(
          COLUMN_NAME, 
          '(', 
          SUB_PART, 
          ')'
        )
      )
      ORDER BY SEQ_IN_INDEX 
      SEPARATOR ', '
    ) AS indexed_columns
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.STATISTICS
  GROUP BY TABLE_NAME, INDEX_NAME
) AS second_part
  ON first_part.TABLE_NAME = second_part.TABLE_NAME
  AND first_part.INDEX_NAME != second_part.INDEX_NAME
  AND first_part.indexed_columns LIKE CONCAT(second_part.indexed_columns, '%')
```

Comment: I did a few tweaks to your query so:
1. It will return only the index with most columns from a set of supersets
2. It will not confuse two different columns with one name containing the other, like "status" and "statusid" (posting below because if comment length limitation)
3. It won't include PRIMARY indexes as drop candidates
4. It won't suggest unique indexes as drop candidates unless the other index is also unique
5. It will not return two exactly matching indexes, only one

Answer (score 2):

There is *no* way to find unused indexes.  There are imperfect tools to suggest duplicate indexes, but they depend on watching what indexes are being used -- If you have a query you run only once a month, it may go unnoticed.

My [*Index Cookbook*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql) provides some tips.  Here are some common mistakes:

- Don't a 'flag' by itself; the Optimizer will probably never use it.
- If you have `INDEX(a,b)`, you don't need `INDEX(a)`.  Note: Tools may not pick up on this rule.
- `INDEX(a)`, `INDEX(b)` are often not as good as `INDEX(a,b)`, but you can't replace both of the former two indexes with the latter one.
- `INDEX(a(191))` is awful.  Five workarounds: [*here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/limits#767_limit_in_innodb_indexes) .

A column can reside both in a single-column and a composite index.  In some such situations, one index is redundant.  But the rules get tricky:

```
INDEX(a)       -- Usually can be removed, even if used
INDEX(a, b)

UNIQUE(c)      -- Not redundant
UNIQUE(c, d)   -- Can change to INDEX(c, d)

PRIMARY KEY(e)
INDEX(e, ...)  -- Usually redundant

INDEX(x(123))  -- Rarely useful, even when you think it would be
```

Comment: very good point, an index can reside both as a single and composite key index

Comment: what about `PRIMARY(a,b)` and `INDEX(B)` ?

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam - Yes, that _can_ be a useful combination.  Start a new question with a specific table and a couple of queries.

Comment: @RickJames I just wanted a first opinion which in my case was also the same, i did g through your index cookbook link, your **Algorithm, Step 2b (GROUP BY)** does not cover the cases where you are joining the tables and the where clause and the group by both target 2 diff table columns

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam - My cookbook does not go into much detail about Joins.  Please start a Question of your own, with the specific query and `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the tables.  I will go into details (and maybe update the cookbook to cover your specific case.)  Part of the complexity is deciding which table will be scanned first, then taking that into account to pretend what the `WHERE` will see.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `schema_redundant_indexes` view to identify those redundant indexes since MySQL 5.7.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sys-schema-redundant-indexes.html

Comment: Caution:  "redundant", "never used", and "duplicate" have subtly different meanings in this context.

Answer (score 0):

its work for us in Mysql-5.7.30 (please place db name only) and verify tables which shown more than 1 value.

```
SELECT  -- idx.tab_schema,
    idx.tab_name,
--  idx.ind_name,
    idx.col_name,
    COUNT(*)
FROM    (
    SELECT  s.`TABLE_SCHEMA` tab_schema,
        s.`TABLE_NAME` tab_name,
        s.`INDEX_NAME` ind_name,
        GROUP_CONCAT(s.`COLUMN_NAME`) col_name
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.STATISTICS s
    WHERE   s.`TABLE_SCHEMA`='db_name'
    -- and  s.`TABLE_NAME`='documents'
    GROUP BY s.`TABLE_SCHEMA`,s.`TABLE_NAME`,s.`INDEX_NAME`
    ) AS idx
GROUP BY idx.tab_name,idx.col_name
HAVING COUNT(*)>1
ORDER BY 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        first_part.TABLE_SCHEMA,
        first_part.TABLE_NAME,
        second_part.INDEX_NAME AS redundant_index,
        second_part.indexed_columns AS redundant_index_columns,
        second_part.NON_UNIQUE,
        first_part.INDEX_NAME AS superset_index,
        first_part.indexed_columns AS superset_index_columns,
        rank() over (partition by second_part.TABLE_SCHEMA,
        second_part.TABLE_NAME,
        second_part.INDEX_NAME
    order by
        length(first_part.indexed_columns) desc,
        case
            when first_part.INDEX_NAME = 'PRIMARY' then 0
            else first_part.INDEX_NAME
        end) index_rank
    FROM
        (
        SELECT
            TABLE_SCHEMA,
            TABLE_NAME,
            INDEX_NAME,
            NON_UNIQUE,
            GROUP_CONCAT(
      IF(SUB_PART IS NULL, 
        COLUMN_NAME, 
        CONCAT(
          COLUMN_NAME, 
          '(', 
          SUB_PART, 
          ')'
        )
      )
      ORDER BY SEQ_IN_INDEX 
      SEPARATOR ', '
    ) AS indexed_columns
        FROM
            INFORMATION_SCHEMA.STATISTICS
        GROUP BY
            TABLE_SCHEMA,
            TABLE_NAME,
            INDEX_NAME,
            NON_UNIQUE
) AS first_part
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT
            TABLE_SCHEMA,
            TABLE_NAME,
            INDEX_NAME,
            NON_UNIQUE,
            GROUP_CONCAT(
      IF(SUB_PART IS NULL, 
        COLUMN_NAME, 
        CONCAT(
          COLUMN_NAME, 
          '(', 
          SUB_PART, 
          ')'
        )
      )
      ORDER BY SEQ_IN_INDEX 
      SEPARATOR ', '
    ) AS indexed_columns
        FROM
            INFORMATION_SCHEMA.STATISTICS
        WHERE
            INDEX_NAME != 'PRIMARY'
        GROUP BY
            TABLE_SCHEMA,
            TABLE_NAME,
            INDEX_NAME,
            NON_UNIQUE
) AS second_part
  ON
        first_part.TABLE_SCHEMA = second_part.TABLE_SCHEMA
        AND first_part.TABLE_NAME = second_part.TABLE_NAME
        AND first_part.INDEX_NAME < second_part.INDEX_NAME
        AND CONCAT(first_part.indexed_columns, ',') LIKE CONCAT(second_part.indexed_columns, ',%')
    WHERE
        (second_part.non_unique = 1
            or (first_part.non_unique = 0
                and second_part.non_unique = 0))
) r
WHERE
    INDEX_RANK = 1
ORDER BY
    1,
    2,
    3
```